# Not able to print out fields of custom object

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, javascript-controller

In my client side controller, I call a server side action that returns a `List` of custom objects. Each of those custom objects has multiple fields attached to it.

When printing the values in the backend (server side controller), this is the result I get :

```
allRecords = (Object_Name : [age=1,height=45,firstname=john,lastname=smith])
```

Now when the list is returned to my client side, I'm unable to retrieve the fields.

```
action.setCallback(this,function(result) {
  var r = result.getReturnValue();
  console.log('r = '+result);
});
```

Prints out `[Object object]`. I've tried using `JSON.stringify` and it prints out `[{}]`. Unsure of what I'm doing wrong. Thoughts?

Comment: Without seeing more code, all we can really do is guess. I'm guessing you didn't use `@AuraEnabled` on your wrapper class' attributes.

Comment: Please do not use tags which have nothing to do with what you are asking. This question appears to have nothing to do with `Salesforce Communities`, so I have removed the `[community]` tag.

Comment: Looks like you want to print `var r`, instead you are printing `result` in your JS

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have your aura controller written correctly and that you are also able to send request and get response from server, with the issue you have reported:

> Now when the list is returned to my client side, I'm unable to retrieve the fields.
>
> Unsure of what I'm doing wrong

Looking at what you have posted, you are printing `result` whereas you should be printing either the value of variable `r` or the return value from the result `result.getReturnValue()`, again assuming that you are returning the list from server.

Anything other than this will require seeing more code.